# Can I use database portability to convert an IP -less DAG to a standard DAG in Exchange 2013?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013, dag

Exchange 2013 allows for an "IP-less" DAG, something that exists in Windows 2012R2.  This is becoming a bit of an issue as a lot of software doesn't support it.

I want to take my 3 node DAG and convert it into something more standard. Can I do something like this:

1. Dismount all DBs (when fully synchronized)
2. Remove one member of the DAG
3. Convert that one member of a DAG into a *new dag*
4. Use database portability features to edit AD in such a way that users are active on the new member
5. Mount databases on the new dag (member)
6. If everything works out OK, then remove all remaining nodes of the old dag, adding them to the new one

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to edit anything in AD, databases can be freely moved between DAG and non-DAG servers.

- Move all DBs to the same server.
- Remove all passive copies of all DBs.
- Delete the DAG; this will leave all DBs as standard (single copy) DBs on the server where they are mounted.
- Create the new DAG and add the server as the first member.
- Add all other member servers to the DAG.
- Add passive copies of the DBs.
- Move the DBs around as required.

Comment: so all I have to do is reseed...? Cool

Comment: Have you ever found a benefit to IP Less DAG?

Comment: It can be useful in some network environments where secondary/virtual IPs are not allowed (case in point: Azure); also, it makes things a lot easier if you are using a "stretched" DAG spawning different subnets.